# /etc/crontab or any user crontab is not being executed

Tags: centos, cron

My server is CentOS 5. When I edit /etc/crontab or edit any user(including root) crontab via "crontab -e" command, it just adds "(*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)" or "(admin) RELOAD (cron/admin)" in the log. No CMD in the /var/log/cron.

Sample entry in /var/log/cron:

```
Aug 10 10:21:33 localhost crontab[31688]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Aug 10 10:21:42 localhost crontab[31688]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Aug 10 10:21:42 localhost crontab[31688]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Aug 10 10:22:01 localhost crond[2688]: (root) RELOAD (cron/root)
```

Result of "service crond status":

```
crond (pid 1345) is running...
```

The command "cat /var/log/messages | grep cron" does not give anything.

Contents of /etc/cron.allow:

```
admin
root
```

Contents of /etc/crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
* * * * * root run-parts /bin/date >> /data/date.txt
```

Result of ps aux |grep cron:

```
root      1345  0.0  0.1   5268  1204 ?        Ss   11:43   0:00 crond
```

Contents of admin's crontab:

```
* * * * * /bin/date >> /data/date.txt
```

Note that it's not only admin's crontab that's not running. All cron jobs are not running.

Any ideas why they aren't running?

Comment: try `cat /var/log/messages | grep -i cron`

Comment: try `tail -f /var/log/cron`

Comment: @coredump - as I said above, nothing displays.
@Prix - see above(Sample entry in /var/log/cron: section).

Comment: No emails either? Nothing in `/data/date.txt`? Have you tried `kill -HUP 1345`?

Comment: @dennis - sorry no emails for root. I tried your command but still no date.txt after waiting for 15mins.

Comment: @ian: If you remove `/etc/cron.allow` and create an empty `/etc/cron.deny`, and restart `cron`, do the jobs run?

Comment: @ian - you're right, I had thought you were talking about a user crontab.  my bad.

Comment: @ I've separated the environments for system cron and user cron (thanks for pointing that out).  No offense, but can you restart and/or check the status of /etc/init.d/crond?  More importantly, does Does the /usr/bin/run-parts file exist?

Comment: The cron output should go to `/var/log/syslog`. What do you see there?

Comment: @ian will you please follow up? Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not figure out what the problem was. I ended up decommissioning the server and getting a new one which has everything working.

Answer (score 2):

Check you don't have a /etc/cron.allow file or /etc/cron.deny file causing jobs to be ignored.

If /etc/cron.allow is not there then everyone can run cron jobs. If it is there but empty I am not sure if that allows anyone to run cron jobs.

Answer (score 2):

The is an error in your crontab, look at:

```
 * * * * * root run-parts /bin/date >> /data/date.txt
```

You invoke run-parts with the directory /bin/date - surely this will fail.
The error goes to stderr and isn't cached by `>>`

Comment: Mine didn't even work till I deleted "root" from the example above. The documentation says I should put the user, but then it tries to execute the user as part of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file named `/etc/cron.allow` if it doesn't exist and add the username to it.

Answer (score 0):

Although answer has been accepted for this question, I will like to add what worked for me.
it's a good idea to quote the URL, if it contains a query it may not work without everything being quoted.

DONT FORGET TO PUT YOUR URL WHICH CONTAINS "?, =, #, %" IN A QUOTE.

Example.
https://paystack.com/indexphp?docs/api/#transaction-charge-authorization&date=today
should be in a quote like so
"https://paystack.com/indexphp?docs/api/#transaction-charge-authorization&date=today"